# download entire page (including the `.html` file,the images, `.js` files, css ,etc.)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm working on a projet,and i need some help
Is there any way to download all page(including the `.html` file,the images, `.js` files, css ,etc.)
using php or javascript or ajax

```
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="some.php" method="post">
        Url: <input type="text" name="url"><br>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: the html and images are easy, the css not so much, what with the sheet-relative paths and all...

Comment: There sure is and you don't even need code for it => `CTRL-S` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to code to do this. Just go to the File menu, and click 'Save Page as'. You might also have to specify the format you want to save in (full page vs just html).